# Xcode downloading is failing again and again

Tags: ios, xcode

My device was upgraded into iOS 9.1, and now Xcode 7.0 can't work with it.

Unfortunately, I have tried upgrading to Xcode 7.1 from both App-Store and Apple-Developer-Downloads, and in both, the download is stopping in the middle.

Any solution for this?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61646/xcode-failed-to-download-use-the-purchases-page-to-try-again

Answer (score 4):

A very useful solution appears here: [Downloading Xcode with wget or curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081568/downloading-xcode-with-wget-or-curl)

**Took me less than 10 minutes to download!**

If having *wget* installed, the idea goes like this:

- Install cookies.txt extension into Chrome
- In Chrome, navigate to [Apple Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/). Copy the link to latest Xcode from there.
- Still in Chrome, press the icon of the **cookies.txt extension** and press *download* to save the cookies into ~/Downloads

Now you can

> wget --load-cookies=/Users/{username}/Downloads/cookies.txt -c http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.1/Xcode_7.1.dmg

Notes:

- Don't use '~' for path to the cookies
- If download is stuck in the middle, hit control-c and run again to continue from last point
- If DMG appears to be corrupted, delete it and run the wget again